How to get langchain stream data without logs?
I am using langchain and cohere. It works fine whenever i used invoke with agent executor, but whenever i moved for streaming and using astream_events i got extra data along with the response. Following is my sample code and response.
    agent_executor = AgentExecutor(agent=agent, tools=[search_1, search_2], verbose=True)
            
    # Get Response
    async for event in agent_executor.astream_events({
                "preamble": session_data["initial_prompt"],
        }, version="v2", exclude_names=["Plan", "Action", "Relevant Documents", "Cited Documents"]):
        if event["event"] == "on_chat_model_stream":
            chunk_content = serialize_aimessagechunk(event["data"]["chunk"])
            chunk_content_html = chunk_content.replace("\n", "<br>")
            yield f"data: {json.dumps({'event': 'stream', 'data': chunk_content_html})}\n\n"
       

and response:
Plan: I will greet the user and ask for their name and location, then tailor my response accordingly. Action: ```json [
    {
        "tool_name": "directly_answer",
        "parameters": {}
    } ] ``` Relevant Documents: None Cited Documents: None Answer: Hi! It's lovely to hear from you. What's your name, and are you based in Australia or New Zealand? Grounded answer: Hi! It's lovely to hear from you. What's your name, and are you based in Australia or New Zealand?

I need only an Answer or Grounded answer.

have you tried removing verbose=True?

verbose=True showing log in console.

but you can do a print statement on your json just for testing purposes from the docs it seems it prints everything(relevant/irrelevant)

You can tell your agent_executor to exclude names that does not match your desired output.
see ref: docs

exclude_names (Sequence[str] | None) – Exclude events from runnables
with matching names.

Here is a code snippet to guide you.
not_needed = ["Plan", "Action", "Relevant Documents", "Cited Documents"]
async for event in agent_executor.astream_events({
          "preamble": session_data["initial_prompt"],
        }, version="v2",exclude_names=not_needed):
       # rest of your code ...

Alternatively you can create a Parser for your agent, but before you implement this code below remove verbose=True
From the docs it says this:
param verbose: bool [Optional]

Whether or not run in verbose mode. In verbose mode, some intermediate
logs will be printed to the console. Defaults to the global verbose
value, accessible via langchain.globals.get_verbose().

from langchain.output_parsers import StrOutputParser

class Parser(StrOutputParser):
    def parse(self, text: str) -> str:
        answer = ""
        if "Answer" in text:
            answer = text.split("Answer:")[1].strip().split("Grounded answer:")[0].strip()
        elif "Grounded answer" in text:
            answer = text.split("Grounded answer:")[1].strip()
        
        return answer


# initialise class
parser = Parser()

then you can use it in your code like this
   filtered_content = parser.parse(chunk_content)
   chunk_content_html = filtered_content.replace("\n", "<br>")
   yield f"data: {json.dumps({'event': 'stream', 'data': chunk_content_html})}\n\n"


Thanks +1, but it's not working. Tried both exclude_names and include_names. None is working.

Hi are the names you want excluded in the events? so if you print(event) what do you see can you please update the question with that info?

No change same attr in event

I am saying when you do a print(event) what do you see? in your for-loop
